# Configuring webpack with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fonts, webpack

I use webpack with bootstrap, but can't get bootstrap fonts in my application.

Path `/Users/and/devel/webpack_bootstrap/` is root folder of project.

I get errors:

```
jquery.js:9077 GET file:///Users/and/devel/webpack_bootstrap/448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///Users/and/devel/webpack_bootstrap/fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///Users/and/devel/webpack_bootstrap/e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Files

`448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2, fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff, e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf`

are generated into `/Users/and/devel/webpack_bootstrap/dist` folder after compilation

I tried [bootstrap-webpack](https://github.com/gowravshekar/bootstrap-webpack), but still get the same errors.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Webpack_bootstrap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "webpack bootstrap test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve | npm run dev",
    "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/http-server -p 8080",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --progress --colors --port 8090"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.9.3",
    "bootstrap-table": "^1.9.1",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.5",
    "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.15.35",
    "events": "^1.1.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-resizable-columns": "^0.2.3",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.6",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "select2": "^4.0.1",
    "select2-bootstrap-css": "^1.4.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "0.0.15",
    "typeahead.js": "^0.11.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var CommonsChunkPlugin = require("webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin");
var BowerWebpackPlugin = require("bower-webpack-plugin");
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: {
      index: './src/script/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: "[file].map"
    },
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
      loaders: [
      // **IMPORTANT** This is needed so that each bootstrap js file required by
      // bootstrap-webpack has access to the jQuery object
      { test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },

      // Needed for the css-loader when [bootstrap-webpack](https://github.com/bline/bootstrap-webpack)
      // loads bootstrap's css.
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'less' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [ 'style', 'css']
      },
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
    ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BowerWebpackPlugin(),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin('index', 'index.js', Infinity)
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Won</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/index.js"></script>

    <div id="content">

      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**src -> script -> index.js**

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap-webpack');
```

Edit: I use [this webpack config](http://andrejgajdos.com/setting-up-webpack-for-es6-react-sass-and-bootstrap/) and everything works.

Comment: start at https://github.com/bline/bootstrap-webpack-example, build it back out to what you have?

Comment: When I build this example project, dist folder is empty

Comment: That sounds like a thing worth pointing out on https://github.com/bline/bootstrap-webpack-example/issues

Comment: Thats true, I will open issue.

Comment: Related issues to this question: [bootstrap-webpack](https://github.com/gowravshekar/bootstrap-webpack/issues/17), [bootstrap-webpack-example](https://github.com/bline/bootstrap-webpack-example/issues/4), [webpack-bootstrap](https://github.com/theodybrothers/webpack-bootstrap/issues/1)

Comment: I was able to get the bootstrap-webpack-example working with a couple of config fixes. I have submitted the pull request and you can try cloning and building my fork for now at https://github.com/fagiani/bootstrap-webpack-example

Comment: @fagiani thanks for response, but that project doesn't work for me. I install npm packages, build the project and dist folder is empty. If you notice in my question, I already use `mimetype` and `woff2`.

Comment: @Matt are you using the `gulp build` command? what errors do you get? To make sure all dependencies are there I guess you need to use `npm install --save-dev` after you have gulp installed which you can see details here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: @fagiani thank you, it works (I used `gulp` instead of `gulp build`). I am new in webpack and realized that my `index.html` file wasn't moved to dist folder after compilation. Now I wonder how is it possible that [this config](https://github.com/fagiani/bootstrap-webpack-example/blob/master/webpack.config.js) works and there is no `entry` point.

Comment: @Matt I'd guess it is set in the [karma.conf.js](https://github.com/fagiani/bootstrap-webpack-example/blob/master/karma.conf.js) which I believe calls the webpack.config.js. Hope it helps!

Comment: @fagiani Indeed it helps and solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the bootstrap-webpack-example working it was required to make a couple of config fixes. You can try cloning and building this github fork for now at https://github.com/fagiani/bootstrap-webpack-example

Make sure you use the `gulp build` command. To install all dependencies  you need to use `npm install --save-dev` after you have gulp installed which you can see details here: github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

In the above project, the entry is set in the karma.conf.js file which calls the webpack.config.js.

Answer (score 1):

You must have this structure in your code:

- index.html

  - dist/

    - index.js
    - fonts....

You are loading the index.js from index.html, but  webpack does not know where the public path are, and he use the default root path. Change the respective output to something like this:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: "[file].map",
    publicPath: '/dist'
},
```